# How can I parse my JSON blob in my Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have a JSON blob that is stored in a Long Text field like this...

```
{
"USD":"1.002",
"GBP":"1.32",
"EUR":"1.052"
}
```

I would like to display this in a Lightning Component in a table in the following format

```
-----------------------
| Currency  | Rate    |
-----------------------
| USD       | 1.002   |
-----------------------
| GBP       | 1.32    |
-----------------------
| EUR       | 1.052   |
-----------------------
```

I am able to create the Component and display the JSON blob but I'm not sure what the best way to parse it would be using Lightning.

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:hasSObjectName">

    <aura:attribute name="record" type="Object"/>
    <aura:attribute name="simpleRecord" type="Object"/>
    <aura:attribute name="recordError" type="String"/>

    <force:recordData aura:id="recordLoader"
      recordId="{!v.recordId}"
      layoutType="FULL"
      fields="JSON__c"
      targetRecord="{!v.record}"
      targetFields="{!v.simpleRecord}"
      targetError="{!v.recordError}"

      />    

    <!-- Display a header with details about the record -->
    <div class="slds-page-header" role="banner">
        <p class="slds-text-heading_label">Currency Exchange</p>
        <h1 class="slds-page-header__title slds-m-right_small
            slds-truncate slds-align-left">Latest Rates</h1>
        {!v.simpleRecord.JSON__c}


    </div>    

</aura:component>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to convert the JSON__c field'cs value into Javascript object and then show it. As you are using Lightning Data Services you would have to use a dataChange listener to listen to the record change. Your code will be like.

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:hasSObjectName">

<aura:attribute name="record" type="Object"/>
<aura:attribute name="simpleRecord" type="Object"/>
<aura:attribute name="recordError" type="String"/>
<aura:attribute name="mydata" type="Object[]"/>
<aura:attribute name="mycolumns" type="Object[]"/>


<force:recordData aura:id="recordLoader"
  recordId="{!v.recordId}"
  layoutType="FULL"
  fields="JSON__c"
  targetRecord="{!v.record}"
  targetFields="{!v.simpleRecord}"
  targetError="{!v.recordError}"
  recordUpdated="{!c.drawTable}"

  />    

<!-- Display a header with details about the record -->
<div class="slds-page-header" role="banner">
    <p class="slds-text-heading_label">Currency Exchange</p>
    <h1 class="slds-page-header__title slds-m-right_small
        slds-truncate slds-align-left">Latest Rates</h1>
    {!v.simpleRecord.JSON__c}


</div>    

<lightning:datatable data="{! v.mydata }" 
                     columns="{!v.mycolumns }" 
                     keyField="id"></lightning:datatable>


</aura:component>
```

ANd JS controller will be ,

```
({
drawTable : function(component, event, helper) {
    console.log('draw table called');
    var obj=component.get('v.simpleRecord');
    var jsonData=JSON.parse(obj.JSON__c);
    console.log(jsonData);

    component.set('v.mycolumns',[{label: 'Currency', fieldName: 'currency', type: 'text'},{label: 'Amount', fieldName: 'amount', type: 'text'}]);
    //Creating array for table rows
    var rows=[];

    for (var key in jsonData){
        var curName = key;
        var value = jsonData[key];
        rows.push({currency:curName,amount:value});
    }



    component.set('v.mydata',rows);
}
})
```

Here I am using standard **recordUpdated="{!c.drawTable}"** event to read the datChange and calling my JS method which converts the JS string to Javascript object and creates table accordingly.

Comment: If the JSON blob is dynamic how can I alter this to I dont have to hard code the currencies.

I have tried referring to them using jsonData[i]; i++ using a loop but this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You can use for...in functionality of javascript to do it. I updated sample code to demonstrate it.